# How do you setup Eclipse-like cross project development in Intellij IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Is it possible to replace a project's Maven dependency with its Intellij project, so one can make changes in the sources of dependency and test the effects in the original immediately, without having to build the artifact?

I've been working with the Eclipse IDE for many years. One of its nicest features is that if you have a Maven project 'A' with a dependency to some artifact 'B', and you check out the sources of B and open them in Eclipse, A's maven dependency to B automatically is replaced with B's project dependency. Given that the Maven GAV coordinates match of course.

This setup means you can make changes in B and run A directly, without having to "mvn install".

IntelliJ IDEA is becoming more popular and many of my clients are using it, so I need to use it as well. And it surely has its strong points, but the overall project management is not making me happy. It would be great if I can -at least manually- do a similar setup in IDEA.

Comment: You can view dependencies' source code in IDEA via External Libraries in the Project Tool Window, but since for Maven-based Projects IDEA strictly adheres to Maven's logic,  I don't think it would allow to change dependency source code this way.

Might be worth submitting a YouTrack Issue with a detailed description of your use-case, so the developers can consider implementing such functionality.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues